# Not getting desired result

Tags: python-3.x

Hello all I am trying to write a program that answers this question "Rewrite your pay computation to give the employee 1.5 times the hourly rate for hours worked above 40 hours." 
hours = 45
pay = 10

So I have come up with this to answer the question 
hours = 45

```
overTime = 10.0 * 1.5
payRate = 10
total = hours * payRate + overTime

if hours <= 40 :
    print(hours * payRate)
elif hours > 40 :
    print(total)
output = 465.0
```

When I do the math though 15*5 = 75 so the answer should 475.0, but for whatever reason it is returning 465. Anyone know what I am doing wrong in my code to make it return 465.0 rather than 475.0?

Comment: Look at your code, and try to find where you're multiplying the overtime rate by the number of overtime hours. That might help you find the mistake.

Comment: Hint: ```total = hours * payRate + overTime```. Convert to numbers and write them down on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Lets come the solution step by step. we need to find out overtime_payrate and overtime_hour first. overtime_payrate should be 1.5 % more than normal_payrate. this can be done by

```
overtime_payrate = ( payrate + payrate * 0.5 )
```

Now we need to find out overtime_hour. This should be extra after first 40 hours. So this can be express as

```
   overtime = max(total_hour - 40, 0)
```

And finally total_pay should be

```
 total_pay = first_40_hours_pay + extra_overtime_pay
 first_40_hours_pay = min(total_hour, 40 ) * payrate
 extra_overtime_pay = max( total_hour - 40 , 0 ) * overtime_payrate
```

So complete solution will be like

```
payrate = int(input())
total_hour = int(input())
normal_hour = min( total_hour , 40 )
overtime_hour = max( total_hour - 40, 0 )
overtime_payrate = (payrate + payrate * 0.5 ) # 1.5% pay during overtime

total_pay = ( payrate * normal_hour + overtime_hour * overtime_payrate)
print("total_pay", total_pay)
```

Comment: @Cody Gray i am suppose to post this answer as a complete. I heard that whenever you want to answer in details at first you should try to post a summary or your are making a big answer so that other people who are suppose to response at same time can know that i am not posting in duplicate answer. This is any violation of SO law ?